# Vim python support with non system python

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to build vim with python support, but using a custom-built python somewhere in my $HOME directory (say $HOME/python2.6). Unfortunately, even giving --with-python-config-dir=$HOME/python2.6/lib/python2.6/config does not prevent vim configure to look into the python in /usr. Is there a way around that that does not involve hand editing makefiles ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just glancing at the configure file it looks like you can set the path to the python executable using an env var 'vi_cv_path_python'. So:

```
vi_cv_path_python=~/bin/python ./configure --enable-pythoninterp
```

Replacing ~/bin/python with the appropriate path for your install of course.

Comment: Note that it looks like the $vi_cv_path_python variable needs an absolute path (and would not pick up "~/..."), if I remember correctly. An alternative would be to prepend the path to your python/python2 binary to $PATH.